# What will be the scope of a MACRO defined inside a structure?

Tags: c

I came across the below declaration ; what will be the scope of this MACRO ?

```
typedef struct Hdr_s {
#define MACRO1   1
#define MACRO2       2
#define MACRO3   3
unsigned char  Flag;          
unsigned char  Offset; 
unsigned short cpy_len_offset;
unsigned char  cpy_offset;
}Hdr_t;
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A macro definition remains for the whole remainder of the compilation, and macros aren't scoped.

Comment: Is it after the first usage of the structure ?

Comment: @lxusr, these macros have nothing to do with that structure. You could just as well have placed them at the beginning of the file. They're not part of the compilation. When the compiler starts compiling that file, the `#define` lines will be removed altogether as if they never existed. These are just global definitions for the preprocessor, they have nothing to do with the compiler or indeed with the code.

Comment: no, it has nothing to do with the usage of the structure. Macros are just textual replacements that take action once the `#define` had been met for the first time.

Comment: @Radu, they are part of the compilation, but in a much earlier phase than the interpretation of the `typedef`.

Answer (score 0):

There is no "scope" for macros, once they are defined they exist until the end of the compilation unit. (or until `#undef`).

The scope of blocks enclosed by brackets is defined by the compiler, while the macros are replaced before the compilation.

Answer (score 0):

Macros are pre-processor directives, they don't have scope.